# Check if array index is greater than value in loop

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, loops, laravel-blade

I am running through an basic for loop like this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
$('#sliderAppendNumCh').append(
'<div>'+{{ $i + 1 }}+' Name: <input type=\"text\" value=\"{{ $work[$i]['name'] }}\">'
 +'</div>');
@endfor
```

> for loop is created with laravel blade (php) and inside it I just
>   append some data from my database.

Is it possible to check if

```
$i in $work[$i]['name']
```

My question: Is creater than count, and removing the value if that happens(and keep appending afterwards empty inputs)?

Comment: Preprocess data in model/controller and just display data in view.

Comment: I am displaying my data in my view the code works above

Comment: If code works as expected, what is the question about?

Comment: you read the question?

Comment: I have read it and commented **preprocess** data in your model or controller NOT in your view. Another "valid" suggestion is to create helper function and apply it inside view.

Comment: I'm not sure what your'e asking. If the $index is in the $work array, let it `.append()`?

Comment: I want to check if the $i exceeds $count in the value

Comment: So you want to show the value attribute only if `$work[$i]['name']` value is greater than $count? But if the variable is a name, how do you want to compare it? Or is `$work[$i]['name']` an integer instead of a string?

Comment: I want to show the value $work[$i]['name'] if value is less than $count, and I want to show something else or nothing if it is greater, I am not quite sure how to compare it that is why I am asking:)

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this?

```
value=\"{{ ($work[$i]['name'] < $count) ? $work[$i]['name'] : '' }}\"
```